# Fetching JSON Data in JQuery Dialog Dynamically in a table per button click

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to create a button on every row in a table that is fetched from Google Sheet using PHP, the button must open a dialog with two tabs each with some information in a specific format from the Google Sheet.

**1. What have been done:**

- I fetched the data as JSON, following is the code:

```
    <?PHP 
      define("API_KEY", "XXXXXX");
      $url = sprintf('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetID}/values/{sheetName}?key=%s', API_KEY);
      $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
      $rows = $json->values;         
        foreach($rows as $row){
          $plainText -> authors = $row[7];
          $plainText -> paperTitle = $row[5];
          $plainText -> publisher = $row[4];
          $plainText -> publicationDate = $row[11];
          //$plainText = $authors . ',"' . $paperTitle . ',"' . $publisher . ',' . $publicationDate;
          $JSONplainText = json_encode($plainText);
          echo $JSONplainText;
        }
    ?>
```

- I created the button on every table row with its dialog, tested it in a simple way (having a class in the table and referring to the closest  tag, following is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none; ">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tab-text">Plain Text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-bib">BibTeX</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-text"><p id="myDialogText" class="data"></p></div>
    <div id="tab-bib"><p id="myDialogBib" class="data"></p></div>
  </div>
</div>
<tr>
    <td class = "nr"> < ? = ucwords(strtolower($row[$indices['other_authors']])) ? > </td> 
    <td class = "ar"> < ? = $row[$indices['college']] ? > </td> 
    <td > < ? = $row[$indices['department']] ? > </td> 
    <td > < button type = "button" lass = "citation-button" > Cite This < /button></td >
</tr>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Cite This",
        show: 'slide',
        hide: 'slide',
        width: 500,
        position: ['center', 35],
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        },
        buttons: {
            "COPY": function() {
                document.execCommand("copy");
                alert("Copied to clipboard");
            }
        }
    });
    $(".citation-button").click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
        var $text = $row.find(".nr").text(); // Find the text
        var $row2 = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $text2 = $row2.find(".ar").text();
        // Let's test it out
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $("#myDialogText").text($text);
        $("#myDialogBib").text($text2);
    });
});
```

**2. The Problem:**
I want to use the fetched JSON in the dialog based on the row where the button has clicked and I have no clue on how to do it!

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. https://jsbin.com/nurericumo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It works is this way yes, but I want to take the data from the JSON and use it instead of the simple way of the class name.. Hope you understand the issue!

Comment: So are you trying to fetch the json object on the client side in javascript and then update the template or are you trying to add the json object to your html markup and then us it when the button is clicked?

Comment: I am trying to fetch the JSON data of the row in which the button is clicked in the dialog on the client-side, no edit needed only copying the data.